# DBT: var function with two internal functions as variables

Tags: dbt

dbt 'var function' looks can not accept sql function as a variable, is there any way can handel this kinda problem? Thanks!

As the official document says, The var() function takes an optional second argument, `default`. If this argument is provided, then it will be the default value for the variable if one is not explicitly defined.
Right now, I wanna set `current_date` function as default variable, and it will excute the value that I define the var() in project.yml if there is one.

what I did now:

```
select
user_id,
'{{ var("date","current_date") }}' as dt
from table1
```

in yml:

```
vars:
#    date: XXX
    current_date: current_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: Use the `datetime` package from DBT's `modules` library (https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/modules). This will give you the date from the server where you are running DBT at compliation time.

```
select
user_id,
'{{ var("date", modules.datetime.date.today()) }}' as dt
from table1
```

Option 2: Use a dummy for comparison in Jinja and output the appropriate SQL. This will give you the date from the destination server at the time the query is run.

```
select
user_id,
{%- if var("date", "dummy") == 'dummy' %}
  current_date() as dt
{%- else %}
  {{ var("date", "dummy") }} as dt 
{%- endif %}
from table1
```